# How to integrate textlocal in lumen

Tags: lumen

A stepwise implementation of textlocal in lumen 5.8.

Please suggest or provide an example of textlocal implementation in lumen framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the Textlocal documentation.
Use PHP GET code in the lumen to send the SMS. It will start working.

Link: https://api.textlocal.in/docs/